# Angular get the current form in the html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm wondering if it is possible to retrieve the current form in a html template.

To be clear, I actually would like to reuse some form fields this way:

```
<form name="myForm">
    <div ng-include src="'templates/form-field/email.html'">
    <div ng-include src="'templates/form-field/password.html'">
</form>
```

Here is templates/form-field/email.html:

```
<div>
    <label>Email:</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="data.email" ng-required="true">
</div>
<div ng-show="myForm.email.$error.required && myForm.email.$touched" class="error">Email is required</div>
<div ng-show="myForm.email.$error.email && myForm.email.$touched" class="error">Email is not valid</div>
```

So this works well and allows me to re-use HTML components including error messages. 
However, I have to to give a static name to my form (here "MyForm")

Is there any way to retrieve the current form inside the tags?

I'm quite new with angular so there may even be better ways to achieve the same behavior (i.e. re-use html components / error messages) that I'm not aware of.

I'm interesting in any solution as long as it does not include any 3rd parties.

Maybe using $scope to define the name of the form?

Comment: What you are trying to do is better achieved with directives....

Answer (score 3):

With `ng-include` it creates a child scope from the parent so the data is only shared one-way, from parent to child. You will need to create a directive instead and set `scope` to `false`, or not declare it at all since that is the default, so that the controller and the directive will share the same scope.

**Email Directive:**

```
directive('emailTemplate', [function(){
    return {
        templateUrl: 'templates/form-field/email.html',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

        }
    };
}]);
```

**Password Directive:**

```
directive('passwordTemplate', [function(){
    return {
        templateUrl: 'templates/form-field/password.html',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

        }
    };
}]);
```

**HTML**

```
<form name="myForm">
    <email-template></email-template>
    <password-template></password-template>
</form>
```

---

***EDIT***

**Email Directive:**

```
directive('emailTemplate', [function(){
    return {
        templateUrl: 'templates/form-field/email.html',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.form = scope[attrs.formName];
        }
    };
}]);
```

**HTML**

```
<form name="myForm">
    <email-template form-name="myForm"></email-template>
    <password-template form-name="myForm"></password-template>
</form>
```

**Template**

```
<div>
    <label>Email:</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="data.email" ng-required="true">
</div>
<div ng-show="form.email.$error.required && form.email.$touched" class="error">Email is required</div>
<div ng-show="form.email.$error.email && form.email.$touched" class="error">Email is not valid</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it really helps. I read about directives and implemented one. However I still need to get the form somehow. For know, I set a scope in my directive to be `{ form: '=' }` and I pass the form to each of my form components i.e. `<email-field form="myForm"></email-field>`. This works great, but any idea on how to avoid passing the form to each component? (since the name of the form can be anything)

Comment: When you do not specify the scope in the directive or initialize it as `false` then the scope is shared between the controller and the directive so you do not need to pass it along as an attribute.

Comment: Yes I got that, but then I'd have to give the same name to all my forms.

Comment: Check out my edit above. By passing along the name of the form as an attribute you can access it from the template using the directive's scope variable. http://plnkr.co/edit/qGNJjljcjHw6lklbDXGk?p=preview

Comment: Hum, yes but I was already able to give the form directly as an attribute to my directive using the scope option, and it already works as expected. I just wanted to avoid passing the same extra parameter to each component but that may not be easily possible.